# how to make html canvas undo and redo function?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, undo, redo

first of all, sorry for my poor english.
I have a trouble to make redo and undo function in my application.. i already had read other questions and answers but failed to apply to my project. The recent answer i tried to follow is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150610/undo-redo-for-paint-program-canvas) one.

my html code

```
<th><img src="images/undo.png" onclick="undoLastPoint()"></th>
<th><img src="images/redo.png" onclick="()"></th>
```

my javascript code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var isDrawing=false;

function pencil () {

canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    isDrawing = true;
    ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);

};
canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    if (isDrawing) {
        ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
      ctx.stroke();

    }
};
canvas.onmouseup = function() {
    isDrawing = false;
};
}

function undoLastPoint() {

// remove the last drawn point from the drawing array
var lastPoint=points.pop();

// add the "undone" point to a separate redo array
redoStack.unshift(lastPoint);

// redraw all the remaining points
redrawAll();
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}
```

Comment: Don't know why my html code doesn't show :( i made image button..

    <th><img src="images/undo.png" onclick="undoLastPoint()"></th>
    <th><img src="images/redo.png" onclick="()"></th>

Comment: Have you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17150610/8765205

Comment: @marcel.js That post is mentioned in the top of this question

Comment: @marcel.js Yes. this is what i link in the body. I tried to follow this one, but failed :(.. anyway thanks

Comment: You aren't adding anything to the `points` array..

Comment: @H77 When I tried it alone, I defined things like 'var points=[];'  But It didn't work as i want, so i just uploaded code that work well except my wrong code..