# How to draw this splashing effect with canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

[image: gif picture]

I found this brush-like effect in an app, and I wanted to do the same in canvas.

Can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368784/draw-on-html5-canvas-using-a-mouse

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But what I want to draw is this splashing effect.

Comment: Try this one:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128781/drawing-to-canvas-like-in-paint

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't look like what I want.

Comment: Hmm, then you have to try to modify and search and then implement it

Comment: You will get lots of great ideas, including the spray effect, from this article: [Exploring canvas drawing techniques](http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques/)

Comment: You should learn how to do this by your self, dont ask someone to write the code for you.